# Is it possible to send additional data with parse push notifications using cloud?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

Is it possible to put extra data into your push notification using cloud, that would not show up in your notification bar but you could still pull it from the notification? It would look something like this:

```
Parse.Push.send({
    where : pushQuery,
    data: {
        alert : "You have a new reminder!"
        // *** HERE ***
        // extraData : someData (It would be a, String)
    }
}).then(function() {
    response.success("Push was sent successfully!")
}, function(error) {
    response.error("Push failed to send with error: " + error.message);
});
```

Comment: Yes Look at their API docs, they explain the Json packet that is required, and you can extend it.

Comment: Could you please send me the link of the place they mention it? I went all through their docs and couldn't find anything on this. I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: sorry I didn't have the time & was on my mobile. Looks like [Kriz has found the info for you in the meantime.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35004714/383414)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can add additional data to the dictionary, just like the "alert" example:

```
Parse.Push.send({
where : pushQuery,
data: {
    alert : "You have a new reminder!",
    // *** HERE ***
    // extraData : someData (It would be a, String)

    // Extra data:
    title: "Some title text",
    yourMessage: "Some message text",
    objectId1: "Some object id"
}
}).then(function() {
    response.success("Push was sent successfully!")
}, function(error) {
    response.error("Push failed to send with error: " + error.message);
});
```

You can also add object ids which you can use to retrieve objects after receiving the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that shows what to do: http://androidbook.com/akc/display?url=DisplayNoteIMPURL&reportId=4553&ownerUserId=android

```
JSONObject data = getJSONDataMessageForIntent();
        ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
        push.setChannel("ch1");
        push.setData(data);
        push.sendInBackground();
```

Comment: Correct, but that is for sending the push directly from the app which has security flaws. That's why they suggested using cloud back-end for this. Even if that was possible, I'm not quite sure how I can access my ParsePush object since I don't have any reference to it.